# Retrieve only last record of each group between range

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

**My table is**

```
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|  id   | invoice_number | user_id | created_date | next_contact_date |
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 42699 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-09        |
| 42693 |            100 |     236 | 2021-03-01   | 2022-08-09        |
| 42694 |            100 |      30 | 2021-03-01   | 2022-08-08        |
| 42695 |            100 |     235 | 2021-03-03   | 2022-08-09        |
| 42696 |            100 |      30 | 2021-05-01   | 2022-08-02        |
| 42697 |            100 |     235 | 2021-05-03   | 2022-08-04        |
| 42698 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-04   | 2022-08-02        |
| 42700 |            100 |      30 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-08        |
| 42701 |            100 |     235 | 2021-05-20   | 2022-08-08        |
| 42702 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-09        |
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want to retrieve the last record based on id of each user_id group but only if it is between next_contact_date range

**Desired Output**

if user choose to retrieve records between **2022-08-01** and **2022-08-15** it should be

```
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|  id   | invoice_number | user_id | created_date | next_contact_date |
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 42700 |            100 |      30 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-08        |
| 42701 |            100 |     235 | 2021-05-20   | 2022-08-08        |
| 42702 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-09        |
+-------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
```

That works fine !!!!

if now user choose to retrieve records between **2022-08-01** and **2022-08-05** it should be EMPTY because last id of each user_id group are not inside the next_contact_date.

**What i have tried**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN 
                    (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable where mytable.next_contact_date BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-05 23:59:59.999' GROUP BY user_id)
```

i get the result below which is not what i want.The result should be empty since last records does not belong to the user-specified next_contact_date range.

```
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
|  id   | invoice_number | user_id |    created_date | next_contact_date |
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
| 42696 |            100 |      30 | 2021-05-01      | 2022-08-02        |
| 42697 |            100 |     235 | 2021-05-03      | 2022-08-04        |
| 42698 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-04      | 2022-08-02        |
+-------+----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: But note that nothing that begins `SELECT *` and ends `GROUP BY ...` ever goes well

Comment: you have 3 user_ids and i don't see why 30 is goubled

Comment: And which is why we SO likes well-structured questions and provides information on how to construct them.

Comment: @nbk i apologize it was a mistake upon creation of post.

Comment: @Strawberry i am sorry i dont want to be disrespect. Why you think my question is not well-structured? I read the article you gave me and I do not see that I have done anything different from what it says

Comment: *The result should be empty since last records does not belong to the user-specified next_contact_date range* There is no *next_contact_date range* in your table. `next_contact_date` is a date and not a range. Edit your question and clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas omg i am overwhelmed right now.
I am trying so hard to give you people understand what i am asking for.....  by range i mean a date range that user enters and should narrow the result upon the next_contact_date column

Comment: *I am trying so hard to give you people understand what i am asking for* you are trying but without success, yet. If your question was clear you would get answers with solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a further subquery to catch all user_id, that are in that time frame selected.

and use the user_ids to get the last ids, but sele3cts only those rows that are in the timeframe

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable
>     (`id` int, `invoice_number` int, `user_id` int, `created_date` date, `next_contact_date` date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO mytable
>     (`id`, `invoice_number`, `user_id`, `created_date`, `next_contact_date`)
> VALUES
>     (42699, 100, 236, '2021-05-19', '2022-08-09'),
>     (42693, 100, 236, '2021-03-01', '2022-08-09'),
>     (42694, 100, 30, '2021-03-01', '2022-08-08'),
>     (42695, 100, 235, '2021-03-03', '2022-08-09'),
>     (42696, 100, 30, '2021-05-01', '2022-08-02'),
>     (42697, 100, 235, '2021-05-03', '2022-08-04'),
>     (42698, 100, 236, '2021-05-04', '2022-08-02'),
>     (42700, 100, 30, '2021-05-19', '2022-08-08'),
>     (42701, 100, 235, '2021-05-20', '2022-08-08'),
>     (42702, 100, 236, '2021-05-19', '2022-08-09')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN 
>                     (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable 
>                     where `user_id` IN 
>                     (SELECT `user_id` FROM mytable WHERE mytable.next_contact_date BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-05 23:59:59.999')
>                     GROUP BY user_id)
> AND mytable.next_contact_date BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-05 23:59:59.999'
> ```

> ```
> id | invoice_number | user_id | created_date | next_contact_date
> -: | -------------: | ------: | :----------- | :----------------
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN 
>                     (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable 
>                     where `user_id` IN 
>                     (SELECT `user_id` FROM mytable 
>                     WHERE mytable.next_contact_date BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-15 23:59:59.999')
>                     GROUP BY user_id)
> AND mytable.next_contact_date BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-15 23:59:59.999'
> ```
>
> ```
>    id | invoice_number | user_id | created_date | next_contact_date
> ----: | -------------: | ------: | :----------- | :----------------
> 42700 |            100 |      30 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-08       
> 42701 |            100 |     235 | 2021-05-20   | 2022-08-08       
> 42702 |            100 |     236 | 2021-05-19   | 2022-08-09
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cc2b7c7f4fbfb2084775375dd2d163e7)*

Comment: Try to change the search between 2022-08-01 and 2022-08-05
It will not give you back the last records for each user_id group

Comment: oh yes it does as there are poly three rows left one for each see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a51ac1e686c3420384cb1fa73f185dc5

Comment: No... Those records are not the last per user_id. Last records are 42700 for user_id = 30  , 42701 for user_id = 235 and 42702 for user_id = 236.

Comment: no they aren't as you only select rows between 2022-08-01 and 2022-08-05, and there are as seen in the link only 3 rows left. Mysql take the selecting you make in the where clause and apllies the group by. or skip the dates at all when tehy doesn't matter

Comment: Yes you are right. The request however is that i need to bring only the latest records if and only if those records next_contact_date column value is between the dates that the user provide.

Comment: i think i got what  you want, ut was hard to graos at first hand

Comment: Yes its a bit complicated and english its not my native language. Can you help?

Comment: see my changed answer

Comment: Dear nbk

its not correct.  see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3a5bcdbb0154f8341946c0151d611310 

if next_contact_date is between 2022-08-01 and 2022-08-05 result should be empty.

Comment: Ok i changed it again, we get there

Comment: Yes now it better we are getting there... .but your last change does not return the user_id 30 at all...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232667/discussion-between-nbk-and-anglev).